# Is it possible to get cost data on a destination URL level through Insights?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I'm using the Facebook Marketing API (Insights to be specific) and I want to get the spend per destination URL per day. As [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4#parameters), it seems to only be possible on the following levels:

- Account
- Campaign Group
- Campaign
- Ad Group

Currently I'm getting an Insights report on the Ad Group level, and then fetching the destination URL from the creative. The problem with this is that a creative can contain multiple URL's. This happens when the Ad is a carousel. The way I'm doing it at the moment to give you some context:

```
$facebookAdAccount = $this->_getFacebookAdAccount($id);
$adGroups = $facebookAdAccount->getInsights(array(
        InsightsFields::ACCOUNT_ID,
        InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
        InsightsFields::ADGROUP_ID,
        InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
        InsightsFields::ADGROUP_NAME,
        InsightsFields::CLICKS,
        InsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
        InsightsFields::SPEND
    ), array(
        'time_increment' => 1,
        'time_range' => array(
            'since' => $startDate->format('Y-m-d'),
            'until' => $endDate->format('Y-m-d')
        ),
        'limit' => 100,
        'level' => InsightsLevels::ADGROUP
    ));
    foreach ($adGroups as $adGroup) {
        $adGroup->creative_url = $this->getDestinationUrl($adGroup->adgroup_id);
    }
```

Does anyone know a workaround for getting the amount spent per destination URL? As the above causes problems as soon as an ad has multiple URL's.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is currently not a supported breakdown. Carousel ads are not just a collection of separate ads.